# $A$ and $B$ precompact , closed and disjoint subset of $E$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, topological-vector-spaces

Let $E:=C_{00}$. For all $ n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$ x_n = \left\{ 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \cdots \frac{1}{n},0,0,0,\cdots \right\} $$
then
$$ A = \{ x_{2n -1} : n \in \mathbb{N} \} \quad \textrm{and} \quad  B = \{x_{2n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \} $$
then the following holds,

$ (a)$  $A$ and $B$ precompact , closed and disjoint subset of $E$.

$ (b)$ For all V neighborhood of zero , $ (A + V) \cap (B + V) \neq \emptyset $.

Firstly i check that A and B is disjoints subset of E:  Assume that $ A \cap B \neq \emptyset $ then there exists $ x \in A \cap B $ then $ x = x_{2n} $ and $x = x_{2n-1} $ so we have a contradiction with $ \frac{1}{2n} = 0 $. But i stack others. Can you give any hint? Thanks for all.

Comment: I'm guessing $c_{00}$ is the set of all sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ with all but finitely many elements zero?

Comment: yes it is. $c_{00}$ is the set of all sequences in $ \mathbb{R}$ with all but finitely many elements zero. Also the norm is supremum norm.

Comment: What is the topology on $c_{00}$ we're considering?

Comment: norm topology $ \tau _ {||.||_{\infty}}$

Comment: Do not delete a question immediately after receiving an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person who took the time to answer your question, and disrespectful to future readers who might find the answer helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to show that $A \subseteq c_{00}$ is closed. Recall that

$$c_{00} := \{(x_n)_{n \geq 0} \ | \ \text{ there exists an M } \geq 0 \text{ so that } (x_n)_{n \geq 0} = (x_1, \ldots, x_M, 0, \ldots)\}.$$

We're equipping this with the topology given by the norm

$$ \|(x_n) \|_\infty := \sup\{ |x_n| \ | \ n \geq 0\}. $$

Let

$$A := \left\{ \left(1, \frac{1}{2}, \ldots, \frac{1}{2n}, 0 \ldots \right) \ | \ n \geq 1 \right\}.$$

Let $(y_n) \subseteq A$ and suppose $y_n \rightarrow y \in c_{00}$ in the supremum norm. Since $y \in c_{00}$, there is some $M$ so that $y = (x_1, \ldots, x_M, 0, \ldots).$ Observe that $y_n$ must eventually be constant in $n$, otherwise it cannot converge to a point in $c_{00}$ (think about what our choices for $y_n$ are). Since it is eventually constant, we must get that $y \in A$, so $A$ is closed. The same trick works for $B$.

To see precompact, we need to discuss in terms of what space. Generally we consider

$$ c := \{(x_n)_{n \geq 0} \ | \ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n \text{ exists}\}.$$

In this case, the closure of $A$ is going to be

$$\overline{A} = A \cup \left\{ \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)_{n \geq 1} \right\}.$$

To show it is compact, take any sequence $(y_n) \subseteq A$ and show that you can find a convergent subsequence (alternatively you can do it with open covers).

For the last one, it suffices to work with balls. Let

$$B_n := \left\{(x_n) \in c \ | \ \|x\|_\infty < \frac{1}{n}\right\}.$$

Notice that

$$ \left(1, \frac{1}{2}, \ldots, \frac{1}{2n}, 0, \ldots \right) + \left(0, 0, \ldots, 0, \frac{1}{2n+1}, \ldots \right) \in (A + B_{2n+1}) \cap (B + B_{2n+1}).$$

We can do this for every $n$, so it works for any (open) neighborhood of the origin.

Comment: Actually, compactness is probably easier working with this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602670/compact-subsets-of-c-0

Comment: thank you so much what about b ? can you give any hint ?

Comment: The part with the balls should solve b

Comment: how it is solve i didnt understand can you explain a bit more

Comment: Take a neighborhoord V around the origin. For sufficiently large n it will have a ball of radius 1/n contained in it. This means i can make one of the coordinates 1/n and the rest 0 and that'll be in the ball. If I shift A or B by this ball, I can add a 1/n at the end of my sequence to get an element in the other set. Since it's a ball around the origin, 0 is in the ball, and we get non trivial overlap.